# Unix command to find the size of a file in a directory and subdirectories

Tags: unix

I have a file "sample.txt" which is present in multiple sub directories. I want to get the directory in which the file is not empty.

How can I do this in unix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved, using the `find` command, using the `-size` switch:

```
find ./ -name "sample.txt" -size +1c
```

As size, I've put +1c, which means "at least one byte", I presume that one byte is the minimum size of a file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find files with name "sample.txt" in all subdirectories of /path/to/base with non-zero size, that translates pretty directly to the command:

```
find /path/to/base -type f -name sample.txt -not -size 0
```